# Textlabel in tableview cell doesn't resize after refresh

Tags: iphone, ios

When I initialize a textlabel from a static tableview cell in viewDidLoad, everything is displayed as it should be. However when I change the textvalue some moments later after the press of a button, the text is clipped if it was bigger than the original text set in viewDidLoad. When the new text is shorter, it's being displayed correctly.

Somebody knows a solution for this problem?

-- EDIT --

Solved with:

try calling the label's setNeedsLayout method after changing the text value - that may resize the label. –

Comment: Did you mean an ellipses(...) is appended at the end and text is cut short?

Comment: Yes, the label isn't wide enough and 3 points are shown ...

Comment: This works, but I had to call 'setNeedsLayout' on the *cell* object... not just its textLabel, in order to get it to refresh properly upon changing the length of its text. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property of the label to YES.  It will make the font smaller when text becomes longer.  Also set the minimumFontSize property to a smaller value than the default.

Comment: That's not the problem. When the initial value does get set, the width of the label grows according to the text. So I can set a word containing 20 characters. But when I initially set a small word with lets say 5 characters. When I now replace some time later (after a button press) the text-value with a word containing 6 characters. There is only space for 5 ...

Comment: try calling the label's setNeedsLayout method after changing the text value - that may resize the label.